# Не управляемое многократное выполнение запроса Ajax

Tags: ajax, node.js

Здравствуйте! Существует непонятная мне проблема:
Пишу сервер на Node.js и отправляю с клиента ajax запросы вида (например вставка новой записи в БД):

```js
function AddNewSet_to_DB(storagenum, name, groupname) {

//Создаем запрос из параметров
var jsonrezult = {
    "reason": "insert_newset",
    "storage": storagenum,
    "setname": name,
    "groupname": groupname
};

senddata = 'sendpackage=' + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(jsonrezult));
//Асинхронный запрос к серверу
$.ajax({
    type: "PUT",
    url: "/storages",
    data: senddata
});

};
```

После успешного запроса наблюдаю такую вещь:

[image: Многократное выполнение PUT'а]

Запрос "сам собой" может выполнится несколько раз с пустыми или последними параметрами (был случай когда на стороне сервера пришлось руками блочить подобную дичь).

Полный код:

```js
 $(window).click(function(e) {
 //ловим элемент, по которому кликнули
  var t = e.target;
  //получаем ID
  var elm_id = t.id;
  //Если решили добавить новый комплект!
   if (elm_id == "add_set") {
        window.flag_enableKeyEnterfor_addNewProduct = false;
        window.flag_enableKeyEnterfor_addNewGroup = false;
        window.flag_enableKeyEnterfor_ReNameProduct = false;
        window.flag_enableKeyEnterfor_ReNameGroup = false;
        window.flag_enableKeyEnterfor_ReNameSet = false;

        //Создаем список в модальном окне
        var selectList = document.createElement("select");
        selectList.id = "list_groups";
        selectList.className = "form-control";

        //Добавляем туда, че есть
        for (let i = 0; i < window.products_counter; i++) {
            //Проходим по всем позициям
            if (window.Groups.has(window.products.ID[i]) == true) {
                for (let j = 0; j < window.Groups.get(window.products.ID[i]).name.length; j++) {
                    var option = document.createElement("option");
                    option.value = "valgroup" + i;
                    option.text = window.Groups.get(window.products.ID[i]).name[j]
                    selectList.appendChild(option);
                }
            }
        }

  var input = document.createElement("input");
  input.setAttribute("type", "text");
  input.className = "form-control";
  input.id = "tbox_set";
  input.style.marginTop = "25px";

  var div_form = document.createElement("div");
  div_form.className = "form-group";

  div_form.appendChild(input);
  //Проводим очистку модального окна
  $("#" + modal_headertext).text('');
  if (document.getElementById(modalwin_body).childElementCount > 0) Delete_div(modalwin_body);

  $("#" + modal_headertext).text('Введите название нового комплекта');
  $("#" + modalwin_body).append(selectList);
  $("#" + modalwin_body).append(div_form);

  //Вызываем модальное окно с диалогом ввода
  //новой информации
  $("#modalwin").modal();
  window.flag_enableKeyEnterfor_addNewSet = true;
                   
  }
                
 });

  //обработка кнопки Ok в модальном окне
  $('body').on('click', '#modalwin_btnok', function() {
  if (window.flag_enableKeyEnterfor_addNewSet) {
  var groupname = $("#list_groups option:selected").text();
  var name = $("#tbox_set").val();

  AddNewSet(currentstorage, name, groupname, true);
});
 
 //В другом JS-файле:
 /**
 * Функция добавления нового комплекта в группу
 */
function AddNewSet(storagenum, name, groupname, insert_to_db) {
//добавления элементов интерфейса (онли клиентская часть)
//..........

if (insert_to_db) {
    //Добавить новый комлпект в БД
    AddNewSet_to_DB(storagenum, name, groupname);
}
}
```

Причем не влияет какой тип HTTP-запроса отправлять: Post, Put, DELETE!

Подскажите пожалуйста, как исправить данную ситуацию?

Comment: Дичь. Где-то вы что-то сделали не так. Приложите больше вашего кода. При каких условиях отправляется запрос? Отдает ли обработчик ответ?

Comment: Когда пользователь в браузере нажмет на кнопку добавить новый элемент, вызовется функция 
`AddNewSet_to_DB(storagenum, name, groupname);`

Comment: Где у вас переменная senddata  объявлена? Не вижу var...

Comment: Да, не объявлена.. хм странно, и как она тогда срабатывает?